# Swift - Xcode 9.4.1 - AnyObject is not a subtype of NSArray

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode9.4

The below codes used to work fine two years ago.

it has "AnyObject is not a subtype of NSArray" error after Xcode update.     can anyone help me fixing it?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let storednoteItems : AnyObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "noteItems") as AnyObject? {
        noteItems = []
        for i in 0 ..< storednoteItems.count += 1 {
            // the above line getting Anyobject is not a subtype of NSArray error
            noteItems.append(storednoteItems[i] as! String)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, two year there was swift 2.0 now its swift 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated in newer version try with this ..

```
if let storednoteItems = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "noteItems") as? [String] {
    var noteItems = [String]()
    for i in 0 ..< storednoteItems.count{
        noteItems.append(storednoteItems[i])
   }
}
```

Using `foreach` loop is much efficient, just replace your loop with below one.

```
for item in storednoteItems{
    noteItems.append(storednoteItems[i])
}
```

Comment: belated: yes, as? [String] & var noteItems = [String]() fixed my problem!!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `AnyObject` and `NSArray` for value types in Swift at all. And you should not annotate types the compiler can infer.

`UserDefaults` has a dedicated method `array(forKey` to get an array.
Your code can be reduced to

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) // this line is important. Don't forget to call super.
    if let storednoteItems = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "noteItems") as? [String] {
        noteItems = storednoteItems
    }
}
```

And declare `noteItems` as

```
var noteItems = [String]()
```

If you specify the type the loop and any type casting in the loop is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You're typing `storednoteItems` as `AnyObject`, but then you're trying to call `count` on it, as well as trying to subscript it. It looks like what you actually want is for `storednoteItems` to be an array, so why not type it as that? Instead of `as AnyObject?`, just use `as? [String]` to type `storednoteItems` to be an array of strings. Then get rid of the `: AnyObject` declaration on the type and your array will behave as you'd expect.